# Database URL do not match

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to send user's data to Realtime Database in SignUpActivity in my project. For that  I created a database reference and copied the [url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8imDB.png) that is written in my Realtime Database with the following code:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://quiz-project-6afd9-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/");
```

However, when launching the app I get Fatal exception stating the following:

> 2022-06-21 14:50:24.921 8323-8323/com.dinocodeacademy.maingoquizagain E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.dinocodeacademy.maingoquizagain, PID: 8323
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.dinocodeacademy.maingoquizagain/com.dinocodeacademy.com.SignUp}: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid URL (https://quiz-project-6afd9-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/) passed to getReference().  URL was expected to match configured Database URL: https://quiz-project-6afd9-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3365)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
> Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid URL (https://quiz-project-6afd9-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/) passed to getReference().  URL was expected to match configured Database URL: https://quiz-project-6afd9-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com
> at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReferenceFromUrl(FirebaseDatabase.java:214)
> at com.dinocodeacademy.com.SignUp.(SignUp.java:34)
> at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
> at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
> at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3353)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
> 2022-06-21 14:50:24.969 8323-8323/com.dinocodeacademy.maingoquizagain I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8323 SIG: 9

Anybody knows why that happens?

Comment: It looks like the SDK you're using is not expecting the URL format that is used for your database instance. What version of the Firebase SDK are you using?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I used the dependencies that are added automatically through Android Studio -> Tools -> Firebase. Where can I check my current Firebase SDK version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this, simply change:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://quiz-project-6afd9-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/");
```

Into:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://quiz-project-6afd9-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/").getReference();
```

You need to send the URL to the getInstance() method **not** to the getReferenceFromUrl() method. Besides that, you should simply use getReference().

Answer (score 1):

I think this may come because you're using the `getReferenceFromUrl` method. Can you try instead passing the URL to `getInstance`:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://quiz-project-6afd9-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/").getReference();
```